# a problem with trying to input list of classes in python

Tags: python, class

I'm new to classes in python. I've been trying to make a class that has a list `t` inside of it and each item of that list contains another class. For example, a class with the name `student` which contains two variables (`student_name`, `mark`). Here is my code:

```py
def RempClasse(y):
    for i in range(3):
        y.t[i].nom = input("nom du elevel")
        y.t[i].moyen = float(input("moyenne du elevel"))
    for i in range(3):
        print(y.t[i].nom)
        print(y.t[i].moyen)
class eleve :
    nom = ""
    moyen = float()
class classe :
    t=[[eleve] for i in range(3)]
print(RempClasse(classe))
```

The problem is, it keeps giving me this error when I type the input for `nom du elevel`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/code.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(RempClasse(classe))
  File "/path/to/code.py", line 3, in RempClasse
    y.t[i].nom = input("nom du elevel")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nom'
```

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"? Please make sure to read [a tutorial about classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) first

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nom'

Comment: Have you tried `t=[eleve() for i in range(3)]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn about `class`es you might want to consider reading something like [this](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) or [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) already suggested in the comments.

Nevertheless, your problem was

a.) that you use the `class`es without creating instances of it. Defining a `class` with `class eleve:` as you did is only the first part, next you have to create an instance (e.g., `eleve()`), which then can be used as other objects in Python. Just writing `eleve` just refers to the class, which is something like a template for instances. However, you want instances as those carry the values you assign to them (e.g., when assigning some input to `.nom`).

b.) By adding the`[ ... ]` around `eleve`, your create a `list` with one element in a `list` that contains three such `list`s. Thus when calling `y.t[i]` in your code, you get a `list`. In that `list` is an object that has the attribute you want to call. Just removing this brackets creates a `list` of instances or objects, you can work with.

Below is a working example, however, this is not what object-oriented programming is intended for. I strongly recommend that you read first about object-oriented programming before proceeding.

```py
def RempClasse(y):
    for i in range(3):
        y.t[i].nom = input("nom du elevel")
        y.t[i].moyen = float(input("moyenne du elevel"))
    for i in range(3):
        print(y.t[i].nom)
        print(y.t[i].moyen)

class eleve :
    nom = ""
    moyen = float()
class classe :
    t=[eleve() for i in range(3)]

print(RempClasse(classe))
```

Comment: oh it worked can you please explain the difference between t=[eleve() for i in range(3)] and t=[[eleve] for i in range(3)]

Comment: @BabaGanoush I updated the explanation, however, read a bit more about classes, it will help you a lot. Good luck with your learning endeavors.